# Reverse foreign key with cross reference table - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an API endpoint which will provide summary data about a user and the groups they are in.

My current models have User and UserGroup connected with a Membership Model.

My current problem is I can't seem to get the list of group members to work.

Am I on the right track here? Or is there a better way to handle serialization/querying of models with many to many relationships?

Models:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="members")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_groups")
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializers:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

class MembershipSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='group.name')
    description = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='group.description')
    members = MemberSerializer(source='group.members', read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'members')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = MembershipSerializer(source='user_groups', read_only=True, many=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')
```

Current Output:

```
{
    "username": "User 1",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Group 1",
            "description": "Test Group",
            "members": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Group 2",
            "description": "Test Group 2",
            "members": [
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected: 
'members' contains a list of users who are in the UserGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is too complex.

Models:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as dj_models

class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(dj_models.User, through='Membership', related_name='user_groups')


class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(dj_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializers:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as dj_models

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = dj_models.User
        fields = ('username',)


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'members')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='user_groups')

    class Meta:
        model = dj_models.User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')
```

Output:

```
[
{
  "username":"Account 01",
  "groups":[
     {
        "name":"Group 01",
        "description":"Test Group",
        "members":[
           {
              "username":"Account 01"
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "name":"Group 02",
        "description":"Test Group 2",
        "members":[
           {
              "username":"Account 01"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: How would I do this with the default User model? Would I have to extend it with another model?

Comment: Found a solution that works similar to one above. Just moved the ManyToMany field to UserGroup so I didn't have to extend the default User model at this stage. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam I edit above code. It uses default Django's User model.